# Is there a good open-source Google maps style <canvas> image component out there?

Tags: html, image, canvas, touch, gesture

I need a component based on an HTML5 `<canvas>` which will **behave very much like Google maps.**

**NOTE** - to clarify, I am not looking for a maps component, but a generic image zooming/annotating component that *behaves* like Google maps!

It needs to do the following:

- draw an image
- draw some shapes over the image at certain coordinates
- have smooth pinch-zoom on the image, ideally zooming in on the spot at the centre of the pinch on the screen
- have the image be draggable when zoomed-in so you can change the area of the image the viewport is looking at
- redraw the shapes at the same coordinates over the zoomed portion of the image, so they remain the same size no matter the level of zoom

I thought about how I would achieve this, and decided I'd probably do something like the following:

- use a library like [jGestures](http://jgestures.codeplex.com/) or [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) or [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch) to detect pinch and drag gestures
- use the `context.drawImage(Image, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh)` function to implement image zoom and positioning based on the drag and pinch events
- keep a track of the zoom level and viewport position so the shapes can be redrawn at the correct coordinates on the image every time it is dragged/zoomed
- perhaps use a loop with setTimeout() to make the zooming/dragging smoothly animated rather than all-at-once

However I quickly realised this would be pretty complex to write from scratch, even using a library to handle the touch gestures.

I started Googling for an open-source implementation of such a component, but the few I found didn't have the full feature-set, seem well-supported or have good reviews.

I find it hard to believe that a good open-source implementation of a component like this isn't out there. This is such a common requirement in mobile web apps, and there are already several SO questions around how to implement something similar - though most of these are from a while ago so maybe something exists now that didn't then?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have *heard* good things about: http://www.openlayers.org/ and have *seen* the results of it being used (Intranet project, nothing public - sorry). However, I have not used it myself.

Comment: perhaps not that clear from the title of the question, but I don't want  a map component - just a generic component which behaves like Google maps but with any image

Comment: Oh, that is clear. Open layers does not *have* to be used just for maps. It can be used with *any images* - after all, maps are just image pyramids with layers right?

Comment: Ah, great - they don't make that feature very clear on their homepage! Cheers, +1

Comment: No, they certainly don't. I was surprised when I saw it in action. Good luck! :)